# Is possessive's apostrophe dispensable in any case?

Tags: possessives, apostrophe

For instance, in the following sentence:

> Is it possible to reset columns' width to default in the message pane?

Can I forget the apostrophe, using "columns width"?

I don't see the possessive/apostrophe being used often all over the Internet.

Is it acceptable? What's the status?

Comment: I'm wondering if it should be "columns' widths".

Comment: @TheodoreNorvell I think that would be proper only if you were referring to multiple different widths, belonging to multiple specific columns.

Comment: "I don't see the possessive/apostrophe being used often all over the Internet". The internet is not generally renowned for high standards of grammatical/syntactic correctness ;-)

Comment: This reminds me of the Association for the Abolition of the Aberrant Apostrophe  http://www.writersandeditors.com/blog.htm?post=631948

Comment: here i would use "column widths".

Comment: @ElmerCat I would think that when referring to the singular possessions of multiple owners, you should still use the plural version of the possession. Consider "The owners' cars" vs "The owners' car."

Comment: @eclipz905 If multiple people were owners of a single car, then "The owner's car" would be correct. So, regarding the OP's question, if multiple specific columns shared the same width, it would be "the columns' width". Alternatively, if each of the columns had their own individual widths, then it would be "the columns' widths".

Comment: @ElmerCat I see. Our difference of opinion lies in how we see the term "column width," not on which rule is appropriate. In my eyes, two different columns never share the same width, even if their widths have the same measure.

Comment: @eclipz905 That's why the context is so important — it establishes what "column width" means; what the columns are, what "width" represents and how it relates to the columns. Suppose you had a web page that has three columns: Column A, Column B, and Column C; but the page has only one setting for column width, that all the columns use. Wouldn't that individual setting be the columns' width?

Comment: I'm with @sgroves.  It's the width or widths you are concerned with, so `column` becomes an adjective.  No need for possessive, just use `column widths`.  However `columns' widths` would also be fine for plural possessive, we just don't use it much in tech.

Comment: The columns are "subject", "from", "date", etc. It's from Thunderbird, an e-mail client. I don't feel that "column widths" is OK, since I really want all columns to get their default widths. So it seems that "columns widths" is better?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There are a few limited cases for which an apostrophe is not used to indicate possession. For example, if you're referring to something belonging to ***it*** or ***her***, the correct form is ***its*** or ***hers***, with no apostrophe.

Such an exception does not apply to ***column***. If you want to refer to the width of a particular column, you would say the ***column's*** width. In the plural case, to refer to the width of specific multiple columns, the apostrophe goes after the "s", so the ***columns'*** width would be correct.

However, if you're referring to the width in a general sense, rather than to specific a specific column or columns, then ***column width*** would be correct.

Your example quote is incorrect without a modifier such as "the", so it should be:

> Is it possible to reset the columns' width to default in the message pane?

... but note that this refers to specific columns that need to be previously introduced in the context. Otherwise, for a general context applying to all columns it should be:

> Is it possible to reset column width to default in the message pane?

Comment: I agree with this answer, except I may sometimes add the definite article ("the column width") depending on context. As a programmer, I often have to write descriptive text like this, and it can negatively impact readability to use possessives. Since "column width" will likely map to user interface elements and internal parameters within the software you are describing, it can and should be used in the documentation in order to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: @Echelon: Well of course, in most programming languages, the `'` has a specific meaning, and cannot be used as part of a variable name.  So the `s` at the end of a word should really only be used for pluralization.  Thus I'd expect a variable named "`columnsWidth`" to describe the combined width of multiple columns.  To the answer above, I'd add that the only exceptions to the apostrophe rule for possessives are specifically pronouns.

Comment: Specifically pronouns are the exception to the possessive apostrophe rule (as far as I'm aware).  His, hers, theirs, its, yours, mine, etc.  Not an apostrophe in sight.

Answer (score 11):

If you want the possessive form, the apostrophe cannot be omitted. But in the specific case of *columns' width*, we may just write *column width*, which is a noun phrase with *width* modified by *column*.

Answer (score 4):

For "correct" grammar, you need the apostrophe.  Sometimes people forget, don't know, or don't care, which is probably why you'll see (or rather, not see) a lot of missing apostrophes on the net.

Comment: You see a lot more superfluous apostrophes than missing ones. OK you can't see the missing ones.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's not always true, a word can be possessive without using an apostrophe.

> There was an alien in the UFO. We found its remnants at the crash site.

Comment: Apart from "it" and other pronouns can you find another exception? I think not.

Comment: What about the Lloyd's insurance company? Do you use another apostrophe for Lloyd's' customers, or is one enough? (I don't know, just asking).

Answer (score 1):

No, an apostrophe is never dispensable for indicating that a noun is being used in the possessive case. You may sometimes see a noun being used as an adjective (the example of *column width*, above), but that it not an example of a possessive (*column's width*). The need for an apostrophe to signify the possessive is (with the exception of pronouns) one of the few rules of English spelling that has no exception.